# How to handle client side session timeout in ibm worklight hybrid mobile application

Tags: android, client, ibm-mobilefirst, session-timeout

I want to know if there is any way to check session expiry in client app when it is launched (or when app resumes).

At present I am making use of securing each adapter procedure with a securityTest, so that when the app resumes and user tries to click and make call to server, it throws auth challenge and show login screen. This will get response of the procedure call made on successful authentication.

But I need the app just to show login screen, when the session expires and begin the app from the start. Is there any way without making use of adapter level authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried securing the application on the environment level? That is, provide a security test on the environment node in the `application-descriptor.xml` file.

Then, when the app launches you'll call `WL.Client.connect` and trigger an authentication flow. This will also generate a session between the client and server.

When that session expires due to inactivity for the set amount of time that you have declared in the `worklight.properties` file, and you'll do some adapter request - the server will notice that the session has expired and will request authentication again.

Comment: Yes Idan, I have tried that. But my requirement is different.

I want the app to ask for authentication when it comes from background to foreground. 
If the user clicks home while in between the app and app goes to background. Then when app gets resumed, I want auth to be called depending on server session timeout.

I do not want, to make adapter call and then check the session timeout.

Comment: I can call WL.Client.Connect on RESUME event in Android and get it working, but in iOS, the RESUME event wont fire all the time.

Comment: Then onresume you should do a logout.

Comment: Yes I can do that, but app resume event in iOS has quirks. The resume event does not fire always.